# Unable to coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r, optimization, logistic-regression

I am supposed to get the following function running with starting values 0 (to test run) but where i apply optim(), there is an error message "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'"

This is my code:

```
log.likelihood(params, x, y)
logistic.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
logistic.predict(xtest, fit)

log.likelihood = function(params, x, y) {

    x = cbind(rep(1, nrow(x)), x) 
    Bx.sum = params %*% t(x) 
    t1 = sum((1-y)*Bx.sum) # 1st term
    t2 = sum(log(1+sapply(-Bx.sum, exp, simplify=T))) 

    likelihood = -(t1+t2)
    return(-likelihood)
}



optim(params = 0, x = xtrain, y = ytrain, log.likelihood, data, method='BFGS')
```

Comment: Maybe you want show all packages you have loaded and an excerpt of your  your data?

Comment: I do not have any packages loaded nor has any data been added yet. The above code is just to see if it runs, with starting values 0. Does the logic of my code work?

Comment: still unable to run, same error message comes up. if i am supposed to test run with starting values = 0, are there any things i should take note of when inputting arguments into optim()?